# Markov Chain, Doubly stochastic and Supremum

Tags: probability, matrices, analysis, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose a Discrete-Time Markov Chain has a state space $S = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ and a  doubly stochastic transition matrix $P$ (i.e $\sum_{i \in S}P_{ij} = 1, \forall i \in S$)

Let $\underline{a} = (a_0,a_1,\ldots)$ be a probability distribution and let $\underline{b} = \underline{a} P$. Prove that

(1) $sup\{a_i : i = 0,1,\ldots\} \le sup\{b_i: i = 0,1,\ldots\}$

(2) Define $A:=\{i \in S: b_i =  sup\{b_i: i = 0,1,\ldots\}\}$ and $B := \{i : a_i < sup\{a_i : i = 0,1,\ldots\}\}$. Show that if the inequality in part (1) takes equality, then $A$ is not empty and $P_{ij} = 0$ for any $i \in B$ and $j \in A$

For (1) I know that $sup_{i \in S}(b_i) = sup_{i \in S} (\sum_{j \in S}a_j) P_{ji} \le \sum_{j \in S} sup_{j \in S}(a_j P_{ji}) = sup_{j \in S}(a_j)\sum_{j \in S}  P_{ji} = sup_{j \in S}(a_j)$

But how to show part (2), I think I should start with contradiction, thank you for your help!